# How to pre select (pre click) first, or second table row in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 tables. In the first table I have table rows generated by ng-repeat with ng-click events. With ng-click I make some request and output data in my second table. So the second table is empty first, and is getting populated when I `m clicking my table rows from the first table. How can I make a request from my first table row (first table), or pre click , or pre select, so I can output some default data in my second table ?

```
Table1
<tr ng-repeat="task in todos" ng-show="todos.length > 0"
    ng-click="updateTaskInfo(task)>
    <td ng-bind="task.stuffs"></td>
</tr>

Table2
<tr ng-repeat="stats in statsFromTable1"
    ng-show="statsFromTable1.length > 0">
    <td ng-bind="stats .stuffs"></td>
</tr>
```

So the Table2 is first empty, and when I click some table rows from Table1 I make a request, and pass the data in Table2.

Problem: how can I have default data in Table2, such as the data from the first, or second table row in Table1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-init` directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit.
Or you can use $timeout in first table controller to load default data to second table

Answer (score 0):

you can call method when you are assigning data to todos
For example:

```
$scope.foo = function(){
    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.todos = data;
        updateTaskInfo($scope.todos[0]);
    });
}
```

$scope.todos[0] will send first object of list.
I hope this would work.